# How to return distinct and latest values in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, unique

I am creating an API output by manipulating an already existent API into a format that is more useful to myself. The data that I am returning is the vehicles and their estimated time of arrivals the stops within the next 30 minutes, all on one route. However, I want to only return the latest/closest to the current time for each distinct vehicle. Ultimately, this will output their location.

The output at the moment will display multiple ETAs for each vehicle. I only want to return the closest ETA for each unique vehicle.

Data Array:

The "when" key is a UNIX timestamp that I've already converted so the closest time to the present can be calculated with that in mind. I just need the distinct vehicles with their closest to present time to be in the array.

**Data Source:**

```
[4,"1.0",1546392702443]
[1,"Rainham Road","73559","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394065000]
[1,"Aldingham Gardens","57812","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394337000]
[1,"Orchard Village / Lowen Road","47144","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393347000]
[1,"Brian Close","49216","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394428000]
[1,"Romford Bus Garage","59172","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393384000]
[1,"Dunedin Road","51104","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393949000]
[1,"Havering Park","77538","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394353000]
[1,"Lowshoe Lane","71530","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394121000]
[1,"Mowbrays Road","55944","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393223000]
[1,"Elm Park Station","52895","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392761000]
[1,"Ambleside Avenue","53403","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394378000]
[1,"Collier Row Roundabout / Rex Close","48309","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393135000]
[1,"Mercury Gardens","47576","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393535000]
[1,"Collier Row / Nth Romford Community Ctr","51753","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393114000]
[1,"Queen's Hospital","49960","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393373000]
[1,"Western Road","75612","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393642000]
[1,"Park Lane","56024","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393162000]
[1,"Romford Station","73397","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393698000]
[1,"Park Lane","52666","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394085000]
[1,"Larchwood Avenue","77776","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394265000]
[1,"South Street","74249","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393396000]
[1,"Hyland Way","51331","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394149000]
[1,"Hubert Road","75416","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393137000]
[1,"Alexandra Road","77962","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393063000]
[1,"Edmund Road","72436","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393964000]
[1,"Burland Road","71859","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393070000]
[1,"Hainault Road","72714","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394008000]
[1,"Hulse Avenue","76441","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393180000]
[1,"Ambleside Avenue","74747","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392814000]
[1,"Askwith Road","52966","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393850000]
[1,"Harrow Lodge Park","73439","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393016000]
[1,"Brian Close","49216","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392692000]
[1,"Ford Lane","52759","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394135000]
[1,"South Street","74249","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393810000]
[1,"Roneo Corner","55531","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393272000]
[1,"Burland Road","75140","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394230000]
[1,"Abbs Cross Academy","52797","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392842000]
[1,"Romford Station","49501","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393556000]
[1,"Elm Park Station","52895","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394491000]
[1,"Albyns Close","74075","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392990000]
[1,"Hainault Road","50589","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393247000]
[1,"Stanley Road","56432","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394319000]
[1,"Romford Market","50889","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393496000]
[1,"Ford Lane","48503","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393021000]
[1,"Stanley Road South","71094","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394007000]
[1,"Betterton Road","54000","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393891000]
[1,"Rom Valley Way","76837","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393475000]
[1,"Elm Park Station","53957","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394428000]
[1,"Parklands School","56285","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393319000]
[1,"Rainham Road","55548","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393104000]
[1,"Rom Valley Way","48861","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393775000]
[1,"Jersey Road","56854","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392978000]
[1,"Roneo Corner / Tesco","50919","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394051000]
[1,"Abbs Cross Lane","73487","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392996000]
[1,"Elm Park Station","53957","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392701000]
[1,"Spencer Road","51914","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546393865000]
[1,"Alexandra Road","47688","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394086000]
[1,"Abbs Cross Academy","74552","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394390000]
[1,"Cedar Road","47861","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393887000]
[1,"Havering Park","77538","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546392970000]
[1,"Abbs Cross Gardens","50324","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394272000]
[1,"Wood Lane","54950","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394299000]
[1,"Stanley Road","55569","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392887000]
[1,"Mungo Park Road / South End Road","76639","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394210000]
[1,"The Avenue","56758","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393401000]
[1,"Roneo Corner","50837","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394010000]
[1,"Hyland Way","77235","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393088000]
[1,"Karen Close","52831","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393236000]
[1,"Elm Parade","56138","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394442000]
[1,"Harrow Lodge Park","77899","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394191000]
[1,"Queen's Hospital","57842","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393871000]
[1,"The Avenue","75285","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393769000]
[1,"Freeborne Gardens","49992","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394275000]
[1,"Kingaby Gardens","58099","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BAO",1546394234000]
[1,"Hunters Grove","56656","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546392975000]
[1,"Freeborne Gardens","47360","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392928000]
[1,"Suttons Avenue","58972","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546394341000]
[1,"Philip Road","58662","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393195000]
[1,"Parklands School","50482","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393959000]
[1,"Suttons Avenue","71292","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392861000]
[1,"Orchard Village","76755","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393382000]
[1,"Collier Row / Nth Romford Community Ctr","59145","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394187000]
[1,"Larchwood Avenue","48236","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393010000]
[1,"Wood Lane","49222","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392888000]
[1,"Aldingham Gardens","75138","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392867000]
[1,"Hunters Grove","56619","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394293000]
[1,"Elm Parade","58876","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392736000]
[1,"Romford Bus Garage","55211","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393789000]
[1,"Spencer Road","92097","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546393354000]
[1,"Western Road","55182","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BFK",1546393574000]
[1,"Elm Parade","56138","N365",2,"Orchard Village","LX11BAO",1546392709000]
[1,"Hillfoot Road","49241","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546394080000]
[1,"Romford Market","49147","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546393714000]
[1,"Brian Close","49058","N365",1,"Havering Park","LX11BJJ",1546392796000]
```

**Current code:**

```
$csvData = array();

$count = 0;

while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($count != 0){
        $row = str_replace("[", "", $row);
        $row = str_replace("]", "", $row);

        $csvData[] = $row;
    }

    $count++;
}

$array = array();

foreach($csvData as $data){
    $array[] = [
        "stop" => $data[1],
        "stopID" => $data[2],
        "route" => $data[3],
        "direction" => $data[4],
        "dest" => $data[5],
        "reg" => $data[6],
        "fleet" => "00000",
        "when" => date("H:i", $data[7] / 1000),
    ];
}

print_r($array);
```

**My Array Output**

```
            Array
            (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Rainham Road
                    [stopID] => 73559
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:54
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Aldingham Gardens
                    [stopID] => 57812
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:58
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Orchard Village / Lowen Road
                    [stopID] => 47144
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:42
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Brian Close
                    [stopID] => 49216
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 02:00
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Romford Bus Garage
                    [stopID] => 59172
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:43
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Dunedin Road
                    [stopID] => 51104
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:52
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Havering Park
                    [stopID] => 77538
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:59
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Lowshoe Lane
                    [stopID] => 71530
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:55
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Mowbrays Road
                    [stopID] => 55944
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:40
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Elm Park Station
                    [stopID] => 52895
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:32
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Ambleside Avenue
                    [stopID] => 53403
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:59
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Collier Row Roundabout / Rex Close
                    [stopID] => 48309
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:38
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Mercury Gardens
                    [stopID] => 47576
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:45
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Collier Row / Nth Romford Community Ctr
                    [stopID] => 51753
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:38
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Queen's Hospital
                    [stopID] => 49960
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:42
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Western Road
                    [stopID] => 75612
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:47
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Brian Close
                    [stopID] => 49058
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BAO
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 02:01
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Park Lane
                    [stopID] => 56024
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:39
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Romford Station
                    [stopID] => 73397
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:48
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Park Lane
                    [stopID] => 52666
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 2
                    [dest] => Orchard Village
                    [reg] => LX11BFK
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:54
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [stop] => Larchwood Avenue
                    [stopID] => 77776
                    [route] => N365
                    [direction] => 1
                    [dest] => Havering Park
                    [reg] => LX11BJJ
                    [fleet] => 00000
                    [when] => 01:57
                )

        )
```

*Note: I had to remove some data from the array above due to char limit*

Comment: could you elaborate, which "vehicles" you are talking about? actually there is a direction and there are timestamps - which can be used to bring the way-points into order.

Comment: Distinct values where the key is 'reg'.

Comment: just found that out myself... these UK number-plates just look strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would sort them into one sub-array per vehicle and check for the lowest timestamp:

```
foreach($csvData as $data) {

    /* the number plate is the index */
    $reg = $data[6];

    /* checks if the array for the vehicle exists and compares the timestamps */
    if (
        is_array($array[$reg]) &&
        $array[$reg]['time'] > $data[7] &&
        $data[7] > (time()*1000)
    ) {
        unset($array[$reg]);
    }

    /* checks if not yet is an array for the vehicle exists */
    if (
        !is_array($array[$reg]) &&
        $data[7] < (time()*1000)
    ) {

        /* it only adds this array, either when there is none */
        $array[$reg] = array(
            "stop"      => $data[1],
            "stopID"    => $data[2],
            "route"     => $data[3],
            "direction" => $data[4],
            "dest"      => $data[5],
            "fleet"     => "00000",
            "time"      => $data[7],
            "when"      => date("H:i", $data[7] / 1000)
        );
    }
}

/* removing up the Java timestamps */
foreach($array as $data) {unset($data['time']);}
die('<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>');
```

Comment: Hey Martin thanks for the code. That looks great however it is only returning some of the vehicles and I can't seem to identify which ones it is. When I refresh every ten seconds or so it displays a new batch of vehicles. The ones that are, displayed however, you'll be pleased to know, do show the closest to current time ETA, so thank you for that. ;-)

Comment: @NathanRedbridge this may either come from the API or from the parsing of `$csvData`. just double checked and cannot see where different vehicles could come from (only that the first `CSV` record is whole different than the others, with `4` instead of `1` at index `[0]`). please consider accepting the answer, if it helps... and just log to screen while parsing & while traversing; so you can see step-by-step what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will return the nearest vehicle according to the lowest "when" value.

```
function nearestVehicle($vehicles){

 function cmp($a,$b){
 if($a['when']>$b['when']){
     return 1;
 }

}


usort($vehicles,"cmp");

return $vehicles[0];
}

print_r(nearestVehicle($array));
```

Comment: `when` is not a timestamp and I cannot see how the different number plates would be considered. just run both examples with the sample data and you'll notice that it's not that simple; else I wouldn't have written half a page.

Comment: "The "when" key is a UNIX timestamp " . Is this not how you want to sort your vehicles? With 1:42 being nearer than 1:54, and 1:54 being nearer than  1:58? And you only want to return the nearest vehicle? The function I just wrote was based on the array you printed. It will return the lowest.

Comment: Ok I see. The are distinct values in the rest of the array. My mistake. The first several had the same plate # and I assumed that array was an output for one specific plate #.

Comment: that `when` is human-readable notation; not Java epoch time (UNIX epoch time * 1000), alike in the input `CSV`. the question actually was "the distinct vehicles with their closest to present time to be in the array". when comparing converted human-readable notation, this is also a problem before/after midnight.